# Limit of the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$x_n:= (1,2,1,4,1,8,1,16,1,32,...)$

What is the limit of the following sequence if it exists?

I was watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0kwQhL4j2I&list=PL8Bjm9Mo3lgf3ErHgflm3FN55MN-0KFmp&index=4) where the guy claimed "if the limit point of a sequence is unique then it is the limit of the sequence" and claimed the limit of $x_n$ to be $1$.

My doubt was the definition of a limit (convergent sequence) states "for each $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $V_\epsilon(x)$ of $x$, all but a finite number of terms of X belong to $V_\epsilon(x)$".

By this definition I concluded that the limit of $x_n$ must not be $1$ since there are infinitely many terms outside the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $1$.

I just want to know if i'm wrong and missing something

Comment: $x_n$ does not have a limit. "if the limit point of a sequence is unique then it is the limit of the sequence": this is true only under compactness of the spece and real line is not compact.

Comment: Your argument just shows that it does not converge to $1$. But yeah the sequence does not converge to anything

Comment: @geetha290krm Got it,Thank you

Comment: @Lorago Oh yup, that was what I was trying to conclude (edited the question). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this sequence converges then it will converge to 1( since one of it's subsequences converges to 1) you showed that this sequence doesn't converge to 1, then it doesn't converge at all.